# Emacs thing-at-point in a dired buffer

Tags: emacs, dired

I want to know what "thing" is at point in a dired buffer.

For instance Debug is a "directory":

*drwxrwxrwx    0 10-08-2009 17:50 Debug*

Makefile is a "file":

*-rw-rw-rw-  15k  6-03-2009 13:02 Makefile*

and this is a "header"

*d:/foo/bar/Debug:*

One way to find a thing is to look what face is at point. Is there another way to do it? 
How can I determine bounds-of-thing-at-point?

The standard (thing-at-point 'filename) does not handle spaces in a filename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions might be helpful in concocting what you want:

- dired-get-filename
- dired-move-to-filename
- dired-move-to-end-of-filename
- file-directory-p and friends

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight text using [overlays](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Overlays). Here are a couple of functions you could add to your .emacs file to do this. The key is that we name all of the overlays created this way 'my-highlights so that we can remove just those overlays later.

```
(defun highlight-thing-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((my-thing (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'sexp))
         (my-overlay (make-overlay (first my-thing) (rest my-thing))))
    (overlay-put my-overlay 'name 'my-highlights)
    (overlay-put my-overlay 'face 'highlight)))

(defun unhighlight-all-of-mine ()
  (interactive)
  (remove-overlays nil nil 'my-highlights))
```

EDIT:

You can add a custom function for returning the bounds of a filename at point that has spaces in it. See [this EmacsWiki article](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPoint#toc4) for an example. So if you write a function named my-bounds-of-filename-at-point you can set it as the default for (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'filename) and (thing-at-point 'filename) like this:

```
(put 'filename 'bounds-of-thing-at-point 'my-bounds-of-filename-at-point)
```

Comment: My question was not about highlighting but about finding what is at point. (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'sexp) does not handle spaces in filename in dired buffer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can define my own parser. Even easier, I can loop forward (then backward) one character at time until it changed the face. This way I can find bounds. But my question was about using something existing, a standard solution for this seemingly standard task.

Answer (score 1):

The first character of the listing is d for directories, l for links, - for ordinary files.  There are characters representing character and block devices, processes, etc.  What more did you want to know?  (I've never seen your "header" type.  How did you produce that?)

Comment: Dired buffer is displayed using different faces - dired-header (e.g. the very first line in dired buffer), dired-directory, etc. My question was what "thing" is at point and how to determine bounds (beginning and end) of the thing.

Comment: Oleg, you're repeating your question using the same words.  If you want a different answer, it would be useful to provide more or different information.  Why do you care about point rather than the current line?  Why do you want to know the bounds, when you could use a regex to find the entire file name?

Answer (score 1):

There is never (almost never?) ***a single*** thing at point. There are thing-at-point functions that can retrieve some text at or near point that is a thing of a particular type. So you have a fundamental misconception here.

In Dired, as elsewhere, depending on where point is, you can retrieve a symbol name at point, a file name at point, and several other kinds of things -- all from the same position.

Others have answered how to determine whether a given line is for an ordinary file or a directory.

If you use [***Dired+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), then you can use <kbd>C-h RET</kbd> (command `diredp-describe-file`) to get information about the file or directory on the current line -- its type, attributes, etc.

If you want to get a thing at or near point programmatically, see [***Thing At Point+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointPlus).